# Infinite linked list after linking removed node with next node to be inserted

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, queue

I am trying to remove an item from the Queue, then link the next item to be inserted to the item that was removed, until either my queue is empty or the removed item meets my condition. This way when the queue ends, I know which items are linked to my end point. There is a single ItemType inside the q right now. The matrix of ItemType is a matrix containing ItemType values and their coordinates. The while loop just continuously prints the coordinates of where the "|" is at.

```
void enQueue(Queue *q, int rows, int cols, ItemType matrix[][cols]){
        int n,m;
        ItemType *temp;
        temp = (ItemType *)malloc(sizeof(ItemType));
        Remove(q, temp);

        while(temp->cell != '|'){
                n = temp->x;
                m = temp->y;
                enQueueLeft(q, cols, matrix, n, m, &temp);
                enQueueUp(q, cols, matrix, n, m, &temp);
                enQueueRight(q, cols, matrix, n, m, &temp);
                enQueueDown(q, rows, cols, matrix, n, m, &temp);
                if(!Empty(q))
                        Remove(q, temp);
                else{
                        printf("FAILURE\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
        while(temp != NULL){
                printf("[%d, %d]", temp->x, temp->y);
                temp = temp->link;
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

All the enQueue functions are similar just in different directions, here is an example of one,

```
void enQueueDown(Queue *q, int rows, int cols, ItemType matrix[][cols], int n, int m, ItemType **a){
                matrix[n+1][m].record = 1;
                ItemType *temp = (ItemType *)malloc(sizeof(ItemType));
                *temp = matrix[n+1][m];
                temp->link = *a;
                Insert(*temp, q);
}
```

Comment: In your `enQueue()` function, the `ItemType *temp` variable is allocated but not explicitly initialized before the while-condition `while(temp->cell != '|')`. Is the call to `Remove(q, temp)` which initializes that variable ?

Comment: @J.Piquard The remove function removes the sole item in the queue and puts it into temp, the other enQueue functions will then put in a item. I'm trying to link the item that will be put in to the item that was just removed, so when I reach "|", I can print a pathway.

Comment: Please, in order to go deeper in your question, it should be good to provide a MCVE ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also errors or unexpected results.